# C++ variable no longer exists

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class BaseException : exception {
public:
    BaseException(const char* message) : message(message) {}
    const char* getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
private:
    const char* message;
};

void wrong() {
    unsigned short int argumentCallCounter = 1;

    /// @todo check why commented below does not work ?!
    // char tmp[13 + sizeof(argumentCallCounter)];

    /// @todo but this works
    char* tmp = new char[13 + sizeof(argumentCallCounter)];
    sprintf(tmp, "No %u argument", argumentCallCounter);

    throw BaseException(tmp);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        wrong();
    } catch (BaseException e) {
        cout << e.getMessage() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code above works, but in comments, there is a code segment, that does not work.
`char tmp[13 + sizeof(argumentCallCounter)];`
I understand that it does not work because when the program leaves function `wrong` the variable tmp no longer exists.
Can anybody help with this?

And also that decision that I write:
`char* tmp = new char[13 + sizeof(argumentCallCounter)];`
It's no good either, because when the program is complete, there is a memory leak, because nobody deletes `tmp`

Comment: what exactly do u mean by "not works"?

Comment: You do realise that `std::exception` already contains a message string? Also, `sizeof(argumentCallCounter)` will be the number of bytes in an `unsigned short` (probably 2), and not the number of decimal digits, so your buffer will overflow if the value is 100 or more. Usually, you're best off using `std::string` rather than manually allocated character buffers in all but the most speed-critical code.

Comment: @Mike - `std::exception` only contains a string in the Microsoft version (implementation detail). You could derive from one of the other standard exceptions from <stdexcept> though.

Comment: @Bo: Sorry, I was confusing `std::exception` with the standard exception types derived from it. In any event, I'd definitely handle the string as a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//why commented below is not works
char tmp[13 + sizeof(argumentCallCounter)];
```

It would not work because `tmp` is local to the function, and it not more exists once you exit from the function, but you're still trying to access it from `main()`.

I would suggest you to use `std::string` in `BaseException` and everywhere else.

I would also suggest you to catch the exception by `const` reference as:

```
catch (const BaseException & e)
//     ^^^^^ note          ^ note
```

---

EDIT:

Implement `BaseException` as follows:

```
class BaseException : std::exception 
{
public:
    BaseException(std::string msg) : message(msg) {}

    //override std::exception::what() virtual function
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return message.c_str();
    }

private:
    std::string message;
};
```

Use it as:

```
 try
 { 
    //some code that might throw BaseException
 }
 catch (const BaseException & e)
 {
       cout << "exception message : " << e.what() << endl;
 }
```

EDIT:

And implement `wrong()` as

```
void wrong() {
    unsigned short int argumentCallCounter = 1;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "No " << argumentCallCounter << " argument";

    throw BaseException(tmp.str());
}
```

Comment: This not works, `error: passing ‘const BaseException’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘const char* BaseException::getMessage()’ discards qualifiers`

Comment: @azat: I think you didn't implement as I suggested. Anyway see the EDIT in my answer. I've explained how `BaseException` should be implemented and how it should be used!

Comment: @Nawaz, And throw I must like this `throw new BaseException()` or like this `throw BaseException()` ?

Comment: @azat: use this : `throw BaseException(tmp.str());` as shown in the second EDIT. :D

Comment: And I want to describe which exception function can throws? `void wrong() throw(BaseException)` ?

Comment: @azat: I didn't understand your question. Could you rephrase your question? or can you ask it in more words and more clearly?

Comment: @Nawas, i can write function like this `wrong() {...}` or like this `wrong() throw(BaseException) {...}`, so how I must write using the second way? (where I set which instances of exception function can throw)

Comment: @azat: If you write `wrong() throw(BaseException) {...}`, then that means this function can throw exception of type `BaseException` only or types that derived from `BaseException`.

Answer (score 4):

I am usually throwing a std::runtime_exception initialized with a std::string.

Comment: How can I generate string? I must concat an integer value there, that's why I using char*

Comment: `std::string` has a constructor that takes a `char*`. So you can still construct the message as you do now, and then cast it to `std::string`. (Do fix the memory leak, though.)

Comment: @azat: you can construct a string by employing an ostringstream, as shown in the answer below.

Comment: thanks ^) But I don`t like way using streams. I already write this code segment using sprintf!

Comment: @azat: frankly, I do not think that "liking" should be relevant in choosing one programming solution instead of another. In particular, with sprintf you must think hard about the size of the receiving buffer (why 13 and not 14?). Additionally, sometimes we are unable to make a safe prediction of the required size. Hence the advantage of an ostringstream. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/stringstream/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/stdexcept/runtime_error/

```
void wrong() {
    unsigned short int argumentCallCounter = 1;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "No " << argumentCallCounter << " argument";

    throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by “not works”?

The `BaseException` should copy the string it gets from the constructor, and make a local copy of it. Then, the `wrong` function can deallocate it in any case.

And when you do that, the local `tmp` array should work again.